# Is there a chain for Python maps?

Tags: python, generator

In Python, it's possible to extend a list in a lazy way by using `itertools.chain`:

```
L = itertools.chain(L1, L2)
```

Is there a lazy map "gluing" operator?  I.e.,

```
M = glue(M1, M2)
```

where

```
M['blah']
```

returns

```
M1['blah'] if 'blah' in M1 else M2['blah']
```

and, `M` has appropriate generators for `keys()` and `values()`.

Comment: Add collections.ChainMap as an answer. An off-the-shelf class is better than custom code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python 3.3 added [collections.ChainMap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap) that does exactly that.

Comment: There is a typo in the module name (should be collection**s**), can you please fix it? I can't do it myself, because the edit would be too short and I don't yet have 2000+ reputation. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It's straightforward to build a class to represent lazy evaluations against a list of maps, and tailor the behavior to your application.  For example:

```
from UserDict import DictMixin

class Map(object, DictMixin):
    def __init__(self, *maps):
        self.maps = maps
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        for m in self.maps:
            if key in m:
                return m[key]
    def keys(self):
        return list(self.iterkeys())
    def iterkeys(self):
        return (k for m in self.maps for k in m.iterkeys())
    def values(self):
        return list(self.itervalues())
    def itervalues(self):
        return (v for m in self.maps for v in m.itervalues())

def glue(*maps):
    return Map(*maps)

M1 = {'blah': 1}
M2 = {'duh': 2}

M = glue(M1, M2)
print M['blah']
print M['duh']
print list(M.keys())
print list(M.values())
```

Output:

```
1
2
['blah', 'duh']
[1, 2]
```

Comment: Do you need to explicitly mention `object` there? Doesn't `DictMixin` already inherit `object`?

Comment: At least through Python 2.7 UserDict.DictMixin is an old-style class.

Comment: Perhaps you should do a deep copy of the dictionaries. Your code will do unexpected things with `M1['duh'] = 3; print M['duh']`